# Android Studio / Gradle - Config for Flavor-specific Jni libs

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I am working with Android studio 1.0.1 & Gradle 1.0.0.

I am trying to use flavor-specific JNI libs which have the same name (and same entry points, only the internal code is different).

I got two flavors "full" and "lite" which for the moment still point to the same jni lib "my-lib.so".

I have the following project tree :

```
app\
  src\
    main\
      jniLibs\
        armeabi-v7a\
           my-lib.so
    full\
    lite\
```

I want to have a different "my-lib.so" lib for each flavor. All the changes between flavors are internal to the library.

I tried to do something like :

```
app\
  src\
    main\
      jniLibs\
        armeabi-v7a\
           my-lib.so
    full\
      jniLibs\
        armeabi-v7a\
           my-lib.so
    lite\
      jniLibs\
        armeabi-v7a\
           my-lib.so
```

But this raises the following error message :

Error:duplicate files during packaging of APK %path%\app\build\outputs\apk\app-lite-debug-unaligned.apk
    Path in archive: lib/armeabi-v7a/my-lib.so
    Origin 1: %path%\app\src\main\jniLibs\armeabi-v7a\my-lib.so
    Origin 2: %path%\app\src\lite\jniLibs\armeabi-v7a\my-lib.so

I got the following Gradle build :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
compileSdkVersion 19
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "xxxxxxxxx"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 19
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}

productFlavors {
    lite {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxLite"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 19
        ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
    full {
        applicationId "xxxxxxxxxxxFull"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 19
        ndk {
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Is this kind of thing possible with Gradle ? Am I missing something important ?
Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not have a file in a product flavor directory (here `full` and `lite`) that is the same as a file in `main`.

Si you have to remove the file in `main` to make it work.